# Powershell to dump database schema to text file

Tags: sql-server, schema, dump, powershell

I want to be able to dump a database schema to a sql text file using Powershell. I want this because our DBAs want to be able to do a diff on the file that is committed to SVN. They won't execute it if they can't see what it contains.

I've found many scripts that backup to a binary .bak file, but I can't find any that dump as a sql text file.

How do you do this in Powershell?

Comment: This looks like what you're looking for: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/04/use-powershell-to-script-sql-database-objects.aspx

Comment: *What* are you looking to dump? Data, schema, objects? Yes, no, all?

Comment: @billinkc I would like to dump all but the data.

Comment: In essence, you'd like to mimic the functionality that is available through SSMS wherein you right-click on a databases, Tasks, Generate Scripts and then script all? It would seem the linked article by @sqlvariant/aaron nelson's is exactly what you're looking for. Is there something it does that doesn't satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Use the dbatools module.

From your svn you need to build your solution. With those dacpacs you can use the following command.

```
Publish-DbaDacPackage -SqlInstance sql2017 -Database WideWorldImporters -Path C:\temp\sql2016-WideWorldImporters.dacpac -PublishXml C:\temp\sql2016-WideWorldImporters-publish.xml -GenerateDeploymentReport -ScriptOnly
```

Reference:
https://docs.dbatools.io/#Publish-DbaDacPackage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

https://gist.github.com/cheynewallace/9558179

```
# Usage:  powershell ExportSchema.ps1 "SERVERNAME" "DATABASE" "C:\<YourOutputPath>"


# Start Script
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

# Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy:Unrestricted -Scope:LocalMachine
function GenerateDBScript([string]$serverName, [string]$dbname, [string]$scriptpath)
{
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data") | Out-Null
  $srv = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" $serverName
  $srv.SetDefaultInitFields([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.View], "IsSystemObject")
  $db = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database"
  $db = $srv.Databases[$dbname]
  $scr = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter"
  $deptype = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyType"
  $scr.Server = $srv
  $options = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.ScriptingOptions"
  $options.AllowSystemObjects = $false
  $options.IncludeDatabaseContext = $true
  $options.IncludeIfNotExists = $false
  $options.ClusteredIndexes = $true
  $options.Default = $true
  $options.DriAll = $true
  $options.Indexes = $true
  $options.NonClusteredIndexes = $true
  $options.IncludeHeaders = $false
  $options.ToFileOnly = $true
  $options.AppendToFile = $true
  $options.ScriptDrops = $false 

  # Set options for SMO.Scripter
  $scr.Options = $options

  #=============
  # Tables
  #=============
  $options.FileName = $scriptpath + "\$($dbname)_tables.sql"
  New-Item $options.FileName -type file -force | Out-Null
  Foreach ($tb in $db.Tables)
  {
   If ($tb.IsSystemObject -eq $FALSE)
   {
    $smoObjects = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UrnCollection
    $smoObjects.Add($tb.Urn)
    $scr.Script($smoObjects)
   }
  }

  #=============
  # Views
  #=============
  $options.FileName = $scriptpath + "\$($dbname)_views.sql"
  New-Item $options.FileName -type file -force | Out-Null
  $views = $db.Views | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}
  Foreach ($view in $views)
  {
    if ($views -ne $null)
    {
     $scr.Script($view)
   }
  }

  #=============
  # StoredProcedures
  #=============
  $StoredProcedures = $db.StoredProcedures | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}
  $options.FileName = $scriptpath + "\$($dbname)_stored_procs.sql"
  New-Item $options.FileName -type file -force | Out-Null
  Foreach ($StoredProcedure in $StoredProcedures)
  {
    if ($StoredProcedures -ne $null)
    {   
     $scr.Script($StoredProcedure)
   }
  } 

  #=============
  # Functions
  #=============
  $UserDefinedFunctions = $db.UserDefinedFunctions | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}
  $options.FileName = $scriptpath + "\$($dbname)_functions.sql"
  New-Item $options.FileName -type file -force | Out-Null
  Foreach ($function in $UserDefinedFunctions)
  {
    if ($UserDefinedFunctions -ne $null)
    {
     $scr.Script($function)
   }
  } 

  #=============
  # DBTriggers
  #=============
  $DBTriggers = $db.Triggers
  $options.FileName = $scriptpath + "\$($dbname)_db_triggers.sql"
  New-Item $options.FileName -type file -force | Out-Null
  foreach ($trigger in $db.triggers)
  {
    if ($DBTriggers -ne $null)
    {
      $scr.Script($DBTriggers)
    }
  }

  #=============
  # Table Triggers
  #=============
  $options.FileName = $scriptpath + "\$($dbname)_table_triggers.sql"
  New-Item $options.FileName -type file -force | Out-Null
  Foreach ($tb in $db.Tables)
  {     
    if($tb.triggers -ne $null)
    {
      foreach ($trigger in $tb.triggers)
      {
        $scr.Script($trigger)
      }
    }
  } 
}

#=============
# Execute
#=============
GenerateDBScript $args[0] $args[1] $args[2]
```